# Why can't I install Gi?

Tags: python, glade

I have tried to get started with Glade software to make some GUIs integrated with Python. When I try to import gi on my code I receive an error related to the version. There is no version that satisfies the requirement. Pycharm suggets to run this command `pip install gi` but I receive the same error. Any ideas?
Here's a screenshot of the trubleshooting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s1fy.jpg Thanks

DEPRECATION:

```
Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting gi
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gi
```

Comment: Fro this I guess you're running Python 2.7, which is a bad idea, as the deprecation warning states. Probably pip simply does not include Gi for Python 2.7. Do the sensible thing: upgrade to Python 3.x

Comment: Thank you very much Adriaan, I changed my interpreter in the project settings to Python3.6 and I have no errrors now when I install new packages!

Answer (score 3):

The package is [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Follow the installation instructions for your platform, for Ubuntu (I changed that python3-dev to Python 2 version) that's:

```
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

followed by:

```
pip install pycairo
pip install PyGObject
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your commands but I got the same error, it was an error related to my interpreter that I managed to solve by following the previous answer! Thank you kindly though!

Answer (score -1):

If you installed python through/using anaconda, "pip install gi" will not work. Instead, open your terminal and use "conda install gi"